# How to get the total of some length of texts using aggregate of mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am working on this text Model

```
const mongoose = require ('mongoose')

const textSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    text : {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    owner : {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        reuire: true,
        ref: 'User'
    }
}, {
    timestamps: true
})

const Text = mongoose.model('Text', textSchema)

module.exports = Text
```

I want to calculate the total of length of text in a day, here is my code ( the code in comments is the one that I want to use but it doesn't function)

```
const Text = require('../models/text')
const moment = require('moment')
const maxLimitCharPerDay = 80000
const rateLimit = async (req, res, next) => {

    try {
        let start = moment().utc().startOf('day');
        let end = moment().utc().endOf('day');
        let total = 0
        const textDay = await Text.find({
            owner: req.user._id,
            createdAt: {
                $gte: start,
                $lte: end
            }
        })
        // const textDay = await Text.aggregate([
        //     {
        //         $match: {

        //             owner: req.user._id,
        //             createdAt: {
        //                 $gte: moment().utc().startOf('day'),
        //                 $lte: moment().utc().endOf('day')
        //             }

        //         }
        //     }
        // ])
        console.log(textDay)
        if (!textDay) {
            total = 0
        } else {
            total = textDay.reduce((currentTotal, element) => {
                return element.text.length + currentTotal
            }, 0)
        }
        console.log(total)
        if (total > maxLimitCharPerDay) {
            return res.status(402).send({ error: 'Payment required' })
        }

        next()
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(400).send(e)
    }
}

module.exports = rateLimit
```

So what I want is how to do to implement this using aggregate of mongoose ( the problem in the part comments is that the part `createdAt` in `$match` return an empty array )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$match` your conditions
- The `$strLenCP` operator counts the number of code points in the specified string
- `$group` by null and get total length of all document's text

```
const totalTextLength = await Text.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      owner: req.user._id,
      createdAt: {
        $gte: start,
        $lte: end
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      totalLength: {
        $sum: { $strLenCP: "$text" }
      }
    }
  }
]).exec();
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OSPX1q3pSnM)

You can check condition like this:

```
if (totalTextLength.length && totalTextLength[0].totalLength > maxLimitCharPerDay) {
  return res.status(402).send({ error: 'Payment required' });
}
```